# Porting C application from linux to windows

Tags: sqlite, mingw

I am porting a linux wxwidgets app to windows, using MinGW and Code::Blocks. The app has some dependencies that I don't know how to sort out on Windows:

1) endian.h
2) sqlite3.h

1) I can't seem to find a windows version of functions like be32toh(). Anyone know where I can get these?

2) How do you install the sqlite3 include file(s) and libraries? I see various tarballs on the sqlite download page, but it seems I must build sqlite3 from source. Is that correct?

Many thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use endianness macros provided by wxWidgets; `wxINT32_SWAP_ON_LE` and others. Obviously it makes sense to use them also in the Linux version to avoid duplicating essentially the same functionality. See the [wx documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.2/group__group__funcmacro__byteorder.html).